# liScroll Newsticker Chrome Problem

Tags: jquery, css

I need to fix NewsTicker  wich works fine in Mozilla but not in chrome and I can't find any answer why in chrome the list lines are double instead of beign near each other. Any hint?

http://nick.georates.net/

I have used plugin from here

http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was difficult to debug. It was *very* inconsistent for me during testing.

So, with a little uncertainty, I suggest you try these two ideas:

- On your `eprs.png` images, change `height="30px"` to `height="30"`.
- Change your initialization code to use `.load()` instead of `.ready()`:

  ```
  $(window).load(function() {
      $("ul#newsticker2").liScroll();
  });
  ```

Comment: thank u veryyyyyyyyyyyyyy much! it works! great! thanks @thirtydot